# Are there any websites dedicated to genre classification?

Tags: classification

I know about last.fm, allmusic.com, and musicmap.info, but they all seem pretty limited or inaccurate, and they don't have much of a community for discussion and classification.

I'm attempting to do narrow classifications of my music collection and have wound up with many questions.

Comment: Some of the most interesting music I've heard has been stuff that has defied all my attempts at classification.

Comment: @PiedPiper - I second that; among other memorable pieces I've listened to that don't fit cleanly into any genre is Waterflame's [Super Swing-Bit Orchestra](https://youtube.com/watch?v=NJkD022lvV4), and from my experience, lots of concert band music doesn't fit cleanly into any genre (e.g. David Holsinger's [Festiva Jubiloso](https://youtube.com/watch?v=H9fQItdL2Bs)), and neither does a lot of video game music.

Comment: @PiedPiper If I get the more well-known and accepted genres out of the way I'm comfortable making up names for the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Everynoise.com](http://everynoise.com/) is a compiled list of multiple genres, followed by sub genres of music, with examples that are currently available on Spotify. This is not exactly a community, but it has a ***LOT*** of genres.

Comment: That's mostly what I've been using, but Spotify doesn't clearly define those genres. Within the Spotify API it seems they're not tagged on a per-song basis (possibly by the artist's main genre).

Spotify has lists dedicated to each genre ("the sound of..."), but then it's totally by ear, without a community to help me decide.

But, if I don't get any more responses within a week or two I'll give you the green checkmark.

Comment: Unfortunately, not all of these genres are recognised by spotify, but certain songs are placed in main genres, instead of sub genres.